# Documentation for admin services in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Is there full description for all methods of [admin services](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS5xx/Permissions+Required+to+Invoke+Admin+Services) with input and output parameters available at one place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find admin services in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/SOAP+APIs

Answer (score 1):

These admin service APIs are SOAP APIs, and most of the methods are self-descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

As Abimaran Kugathasan said... these Admin service API are SOAP services, you could access but can't see the WSDL, but IS does provide you an option in  /repository/conf/carbon.xml file to enable it by setting element "HideAdminServiceWSDLs" to false.